# Ignoring a set of categories

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to ignore few categories from one of the excel columns (Category) of my data-set. 
I had to remove "apple" (a category in the data-set), and it is already done in the code. But how can I remove a set of categories? I tried using list and sets, but neither worked.

For example I want to remove these categories:
`["Mango", "orange", ...]`.
How can I do it efficiently?
Thanks in advance.

Dataset Example:

```
+----------------------+------------+
| Details              | Category   |
+----------------------+------------+
| Any raw text1        | Mango      |
+----------------------+------------+
| any raw text2        | Apple      |
+----------------------+------------+
| any raw text5        | Apple      |
+----------------------+------------+
| any raw text7        | Apple      |
+----------------------+------------+
| any raw text8        | Mango      |
+----------------------+------------+
| Any raw text4        | Berry      |
+----------------------+------------+
| any raw text5        | Orange     |
+----------------------+------------+
| any raw text6        | Apple      |
+----------------------+------------+
```

My code sample :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

data= pd.read_csv('Mydataset.xls', delimiter='\t',usecols=
['Details','Category'],encoding='utf-8')

target_one=data['Category']
target_list=data['Category'].unique()    

data=data[data.Category !="Apple"]
data=data[data.Category !="Mango"]
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give an example of initial excel file and what do you want to ignore. May be you can mention column names and few sample data

Comment: If you want to ignore few values in a column can you just read the csv file all by yourself using python functions and make the data yourself. https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks @Teja , I have added my dataset, I want to remove apple,Mango,Orange Category . I can do it like this: 
data=data[data.Category !="Apple"]
data=data[data.Category !="Mango"]        but want to  reduce the number of lines. Probably I can use a list to remove a set of category, but it did not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
# list of categories to be removed
category_toremove = ['Apple','Mango','Orange']

# use not operator with isin()
df = df[~df['Category'].isin(category_toremove)]
```